# How to detect if mouse is over the menu bar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm calling some method that needs to detect if the mouse is over the (main) menu bar before it continues.  How can I define such a method `- (BOOL)isMouseOverMenu`?

I want to ensure that the mouse is actually in the menu bar, so, it should return false when an app is in full screen, hiding the menu, or when the mouse is in the same coordinates of the menu bar on a second monitor that does not have a menu bar.  It should also return true if it's on any of the other items in the menu bar, but not necessarily when in a popup menu.

Note: my window will not always be the key window when this fires.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [NSMenu](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSMenu_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation the `NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification` is posted when menu tracking begins.

Add an observer for this notification and you should be notified whenever the mouse is over the menu.

**Update:**

I don't think this can be done. The `NSMenuDidBeginTrackingNotification` is only posted when the user clicks the menu and not when the mouse is simply over it.

`NSMenu` does not derive from `NSResponder` so it is not possible to detect it by overriding one of the mouse methods.

I consider this a bug as mouse tracking is defined in Apples documentation as the cursor being over a rectangular region with no buttons pressed. If no other solutions surface I will consider submitting a bug report.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding that observer earlier and had the selector log "over".  It would only log over whenever I clicked on the menu.  Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: The `object` I used was `object:[NSApp mainMenu]`.

Comment: It looks like you are doing things right. I have a sample project and 'tracking' only works when you click on the menu bar. It seems the NSMenu documentation is a little misleading as I would consider the mouse being over the menu item as tracking. I'm not sure how to get around this as NSMenu does not derive from NSResponder so I can't think of any other way of detecting this information.

Comment: But I could find mouse over notifications being displayed in case of some apps installed in my Mac. eg, dropbox ->msg displayed was "Synching in progress"